# How to increase the rate of mails from Interspire Email Marketer to Postfix MTA

Tags: postfix

Currently I'm getting a speed of 5 emails /sec from Interspire to postfix server. I tuned each and every parameter to the max level, even then didn't get any increase in speed.

I'm using a high end centos server with 24GB RAM, Xeon processor, 6 core 
Please help me, I'm totally frustrated in this issue

Answer (score 1):

First ask your host if your hdd is dedicated only to you. I had this problem even with dedicated server..

Interspire is very slow as it doesn't support multithreading. There are mods on the market that solve this issue. Here are two:
http://www.interspireshop.com/webshop/products.php?product=MPS-Add%252don
https://www.maborak.com/

Comment: 5 emails/sec is too slow even with one thread, if issue is not with hard drive then there must be other bottleneck and you'll need to run system tests.

I hired an expert for 2 hours to figure out the issue.

Comment: Yes, the hdd is dedicated to me and I have multi thread addon for increasing the speed from Interspire. Earlier I used Interspire to send emails via PowerMTA, it works fine for me and getting a speed rate of 30 mails/sec even after I replace the PowerMTA with postfix the speed reduced to 5 mails/sec. Please help me which parameter in postfix influence the inbound speed in postfix.

Comment: I am not familiar with Postfix. The only thought comes to mind it maybe your config doesn't allow multiple connections. 30 per sec still isn't fast, if you are using multithread mod. I've ran test today on my server and achieved 33/s with only 2 threads. How many threads did you run?

Comment: I checked it with a single thread.

Answer (score -1):

Try with change below in side main.cf

limitinitial_destination_concurrency= 60
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 60

From 60 to maximum 1000